# How do I get my NAV to line up beside eachother top right?

Tags: html, css

How do I get my NAV to go in line beside each other because I don't really know at the moment  how to fix  it.

```css
#menu { 
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    right:0;
    top: 10%; 
}
```

```html
<ul id="menu">
       <nav>
      <li><a href="Frontpage.html">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="Services.html">Services</a></li>
      <li><a href="hobbies.html">My Hobbies</a></li>
      <li><a href="movies.html">My favourite movies</a></li>
    </nav>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you want to such?

```css
body {
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}

#menu { 
    display:flex;
   justify-content:flex-end;
   position:absolute;
   top:0;
   right:0;
 }

#menu a {
  color:#000;
  text-decoration:none;
  padding:0 20px;
  height:40px;
  line-height:40px;
  font-family:sans-serif;
}

#menu a:hover {
  background:lightgray;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
       
      <a href="Frontpage.html">Home</a>
     <a href="Services.html">Services</a>
      <a href="hobbies.html">My Hobbies</a>
      <a href="movies.html">My favourite movies</a>
     
</div>
```

Comment: Yes thank you! but how do I move that up into  the blue section of my website @ https://alexbruce3000.000webhostapp.com/

Comment: Thank you alot dude

Comment: One more thing, why does my <p> paragraph go inline with  my other <p> paragraph, even  if i give it a class or id it still goes into my paragraph in such as screenshot https://gyazo.com/08292c42b31e566d62fdc57fd995a7ca, my code is   p {
   font-style:italic;
  position: absolute; 
  bottom: -180px;
  right: 50px;
  font-size: 18px;
 }

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `li` class to `float: left;` - making sure to only apply this within your nav menu. I've change the class `menu` to `nav-menu` so that it makes a little more sense.
I've also removed the `list-style-type` so that there are not any dots.

```css
ul#nav-menu { 
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  list-style-type: none;
  right:0;
  top: 10%;   
}
    
ul#nav-menu li {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 4px;
}
```

```html
<ul id="nav-menu">
       <nav>
      <li><a href="Frontpage.html">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="Services.html">Services</a></li>
      <li><a href="hobbies.html">My Hobbies</a></li>
      <li><a href="movies.html">My favourite movies</a></li>
      </nav>
</ul>
```